# messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser message is not received in the front-end

Tags: spring-boot, stomp, spring-websocket

i hope you are all doing well. I'm learning to use Websockets in Spring boot coming from SocketIo in Nodejs. I'm using `Stomp client` and `SimpMessageSendingOperations messagingTemplate` to send messages back and forth.

Problem is, for some code segments, i want to exclude the sender from receiving the message.

`@SendTo` works fine to send messages to all subscribers including the sender.

After some googling, i found the `messagingTemplate` and tried to use it with no success.

The back-end sends the message but the front-end never receives it.

Here is my code below. I simplified it as much as possible, i still can't receive any messages by using `messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser`.

here is the Web config file :

```
package com.example.demo.SocketClass;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.user.SimpUserRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class SocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    SimpUserRegistry simpUserRegistry;



    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        registry.setUserDestinationPrefix("/user");

    }
```

this is the frontend:

```
let sessionId;
let getRandom = integer => Math.floor(Math.random()*integer)

let socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/ws',[],{sessionId:8})
var stompClient = Stomp.over(socket)
let username = "john"
stompClient.connect({},stompClientOnConnected, onError)

function stompClientOnConnected(frame){
    stompClient.subscribe(`user/john/topic/ConnectionTest`, onUserMoved)
   

    sessionId = getRandom(10000000).toString()

    setTimeout( () => stompClient.send("/app/draw.ConnectionTest",{},JSON.stringify({ username: 'john' })), 3000)
  
    function onUserMoved (data){ console.log("Data after user moved: ",data) }

}

function onError(err){
    console.log("thats an error :", err)
}
```

Here is the Controller:

```
package com.example.demo.SocketClass;

import com.example.demo.DrawAppUser.DrawAppSession;
import com.example.demo.SocketData.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Header;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.MessageMapping;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Payload;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.SendTo;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessageHeaderAccessor;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessageSendingOperations;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessageType;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompHeaderAccessor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;

@Controller
public class SocketController {

    private final SimpMessageSendingOperations messagingTemplate;
    @Autowired
    public SocketController(SimpMessageSendingOperations messagingTemplate){
        this.messagingTemplate= messagingTemplate;
    }


@MessageMapping("/draw.ConnectionTest")
public void userConnectedEvent(SimpMessageHeaderAccessor accessor, @Payload String load) {


    String simpSessionId = accessor.getSessionId();
    System.out.println("Received userConnectedEvent. Session ID: " + simpSessionId);

    String message = "Your session ID is: " + simpSessionId;


    SimpMessageHeaderAccessor responseAccessor =    StompHeaderAccessor.create(SimpMessageType.MESSAGE);
    responseAccessor.setSessionId(simpSessionId);


    System.out.println("Sending message: " + message);
    messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser("john", "/topic/ConnectionTest", message, responseAccessor.getMessageHeaders());

}
```

i tried using the sessionId without luck

```
@MessageMapping("/draw.ConnectionTest")
public void userConnectedEvent(SimpMessageHeaderAccessor accessor, @Payload String load) {


    String simpSessionId = accessor.getSessionId();
    System.out.println("Received userConnectedEvent. Session ID: " + simpSessionId);

    String message = "Your session ID is: " + simpSessionId;


    SimpMessageHeaderAccessor responseAccessor =    StompHeaderAccessor.create(SimpMessageType.MESSAGE);
    responseAccessor.setSessionId(simpSessionId);


    System.out.println("Sending message: " + message);

//
    messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(simpSessionId, "/topic/ConnectionTest", message, responseAccessor.getMessageHeaders());

}
```

I tried to print at the beginning of the function and at the end. Both run like normal but the front end doesn't receive a message.

This is what i get currently from the browser console once i refresh my page:

```
Opening Web Socket...
stomp.min.js:8 Web Socket Opened...
stomp.min.js:8 >>> CONNECT
accept-version:1.1,1.0
heart-beat:10000,10000

<<< CONNECTED
version:1.1
heart-beat:0,0

connected to server undefined

>>> SUBSCRIBE
id:sub-0
destination:user/john/topic/ConnectionTest


connected!!
mytest.js:16 this is frame:  
n {command: 'CONNECTED', headers: {…}, body: ''}

>>> SEND
destination:/app/draw.ConnectionTest
content-length:19

{"username":"john"}
```

I had a long conversation with chatgbt3.5 where it basically gave up and told me that the code should work and that i should check my firewall.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Prefix your destination with a forward slash ( `/`) in your script. In your case, it has to be 
`stompClient.subscribe('/user/john/topic/ConnectionTest", onUserMoved)`

And in your spring-boot WebSocket configuration file, also register `/user` as a simpleBroker as follows
`registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic", "/user");`

`SimpMessagingTemplate#convertAndSendToUser` will construct the destination as follows 
`userDestinationPrefix + user + destination`
In your case, you have registered userDestinationPrefix as "/user". so convertAndSendToUser will send message to the destination `/user/<username>/destination`